# Cannot resolve servlet 'XXXX'

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets

I have a spring mvc application with the following web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>publishEvents</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dashboard</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However i am getting the error 'Cannot resolve servlet 'Dashboard''

My pom file has the dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I wasn't getting this error a few days ago but now its suddenly appeared and i presume it is what is causing my application not to load properly.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you change maven-compiler verison?

Comment: If you upgrade it to 1.8 then it might be one cause , just change it to 1.7

Comment: It is on 1.8 but it has always been that way. I tried 1.7 and same problem unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: Did you updated any of the libs? try renaming the servlet, maybe it is some magic word in one of the libs you use.

Comment: Check your version control and see what you have changed from where you have working build

Comment: Update the stack trace

Comment: The DispatcherServlet is coming from spring, do you have that dependency? You showed as you have `javax.servlet`, what about spring dependencies?